# .htaccess slug url

Tags: .htaccess, slug

I'm wondering if anyone will be able to help me, I'm trying to make a site using slug URLs.

At the moment if a user sees the url it is something like

> http://www.thedomain.com/artists-single.php?aid=123

but ideally I would like the URL to be

> http://www.thedomain.com/artist/artist-name

.

I have in the database a url friendly artist name which I would like to use.

At the moment within my .htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^artists-single\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The site itself is written with PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: And do you have a provision in your PHP code to lookup the `artist-name` from a value provided in`$_GET`? The Apache mod_rewrite part of this is very straightforward assuming your PHP code can already handle the lookup logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Apache to access MySql and map "artist-name" to it's corresponding ID, [see here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) (Thanks to @Marc B for the link). However, you could also do something like this though (this is what I personally use),

```
RewriteRule ^artist/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /artist-single.php?artist=$1 [L]
```

Then in PHP use `$_GET['artist']` to get the value, then query that against the database to get the artist's ID. Or you could use the ID, like

```
RewriteRule ^artist/([0-9]+)/?$ /artist-single.php?aid=$1 [L]
```

The URL would be like www.example.com/artist/123, which would pass the id to `$_GET['aid']`

Comment: sure you can. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html It wouldn't be particularly efficient, but it is possible.

Comment: Ahh, I never knew that, thanks for the link. I've edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you make use of a very simple Front Controller.  This will give you the least headache and should be rather simple looking at your current setup.  Have a quick peak at this for more details: http://www.technotaste.com/blog/simple-php-front-controller/

But just to give you a quick starting point, a Front Controller will be "the first part" that gets executed, traditionally this was the "index.php" file.  Using this Front Controller you can then have SEO-friendly URLs and not change any core functionally to your other files.